# My ArrayList (s) are just printing numbers

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, return

I'm trying to write a bit of code that takes a string and translates it like this;
1. Take the first letter and put it at the end of the word for every word
2. Find the first vowel and put a 'b' and then the vowel again
3. Do the same as #2 except for the last vowel

I think I have it sort of close but my output is all numbers.  It doesn't even look like the address of where it's stored.
I hope this helps other people for the reason that they might be having the same problem with printing array lists in a return statement.
By the way, It's a huge code block...Sorry.  The only reason I did that is so I didn't have to put both classes in here.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Experiment {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String pre = "For every minute you are angry you loose sixty seconds of happiness.";

        System.out.println(translate(pre));
    }

    public static String translate(String sentence){
        String[] sentenceArray = sentence.split(" ");
        List<String> sentenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        String punctuation = getPunctuation(sentenceArray[sentenceArray.length - 1]);
//add all words but the last so i can take punctuation off it
        for (int i = 0; i < sentenceArray.length - 1; i ++){
            sentenceList.add(sentenceArray[i]);
        }
//take the first letter off each word and put at at the end of each word
        Arrays.asList(sentenceArray);
        for (String el : sentenceArray)
            sentenceList.add(firstToLast(el));
    //use the addFrontB method on each word     
        Arrays.asList(sentenceList);
        for (String la : sentenceList){
            finalList.add(addFrontB(la));
        }
//use the addBackB method on each word
        Arrays.asList(sentenceList);
        for (String le : sentenceList){
            finalList.add(addBackB(le));
        }
        return finalList + punctuation + "\n";
    }
//finds the last character of the last word which is punctuation
    public static String getPunctuation(String word){
        return word.charAt(word.length() - 1) + "";
    }
//takes the punctuation off
    public static String removePunctuation(String word){
        String newWord;
        newWord = word.substring(word.length(), word.length());
        return newWord;
    }
//puts the first letter at the end of the word
    public static String firstToLast(String word){
        char letter = word.charAt(0);
        String newWord = word.substring(1,word.length()) + letter;
        return newWord;
    }
//insterts a b and then the same vowel behind the first vowel
    public static String addFrontB(String word){
        StringBuilder finishedWord = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++){
            if (word.charAt(i) == 'a')
                finishedWord = finishedWord.append(word.charAt(i) + 'b' + word.charAt(i));
            else if (word.charAt(i) == 'e')
                finishedWord = finishedWord.append(word.charAt(i) + 'b' + word.charAt(i));
            else if (word.charAt(i) == 'i')
                finishedWord = finishedWord.append(word.charAt(i) + 'b' + word.charAt(i));
            else if (word.charAt(i) == 'o')
                finishedWord = finishedWord.append(word.charAt(i) + 'b' + word.charAt(i));
            else if (word.charAt(i) == 'u')
                finishedWord = finishedWord.append(word.charAt(i) + 'b' + word.charAt(i));
            }
        String newWord = finishedWord.toString();
        return newWord;

    }
//does the same as addFirstB but at the end of the word
    public static String addBackB(String word){
        StringBuilder finishedWord = new StringBuilder();
        finishedWord.append(word);
        finishedWord.reverse();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++){
            if (finishedWord.charAt(i) == 'a')
                finishedWord.append(finishedWord.charAt(i) + 'b').reverse();
            else if (finishedWord.charAt(i) == 'e')
                finishedWord.append(finishedWord.charAt(i) + 'b').reverse();
            else if (finishedWord.charAt(i) == 'i')
                finishedWord.append(finishedWord.charAt(i) + 'b').reverse();
            else if (finishedWord.charAt(i) == 'o')
                finishedWord.append(finishedWord.charAt(i) + 'b').reverse();
            else if (finishedWord.charAt(i) == 'u')
                finishedWord.append(finishedWord.charAt(i) + 'b').reverse();
        }       
        return finishedWord.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: When pasting so much code (already a bad thing here) you should try to give more info as to where we should look

Comment: Debug your code and you'll spot your problem soon. I promise.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is you trying to concatente `char`s.  That's why you're getting numbers. Check my answer below.

Comment: Karthik T - Sorry about the huge code block.  Also, I would have given more info but I honestly have no idea where to look.  That's why I posted this extremely lame question here.  I googled until my mind melted...

Comment: Maroun Maroun - I tried debugging on every line.  I had so many print statements in there that it doubled the amount of lines.  I'm still not seeing it.  Debugging always gets me through, though, so that was good advice.  Thanks!

Comment: peeskillet - I'm trying that.  Not getting any results yet but I'll keep messing with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
return finalList + punctuation + "\n";
```

Since you add "\n" with the plus operator, java calls the toString() method of your list, which returns nonsense. You have to iterate through the list and build your own string, best practice is to use StringBuffers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with StringBuffer but I'll look at it.  I took the "\n" off and that didn't help.  I also tried .toString() to all of them and some of them and none of them to no avail.

Comment: @Adam :D the "\n" is not the problem. the problem is, that you are trying to concatinate strings with objects. As i wrote above, you should iterate through your lists and pick your strings out of the lists to concatinate the strings, not your lists.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try to look harder at that.  I thought that pretty much everything was an object and I guess I didn't pay enough attention to what I was trying to return.  I did try to iterate through the lists, though.  At least I thought I did, with the Arrays.asList(list); followed by the for loop.  I felt like I was doing that wrong, though.  Anyways, thanks again :}

Comment: You are right, pretty much everything is an object, even a String. The point is: Except of simple datatypes (int, char, double, etc.) only Strings can be added by the + operator. Thats why every Object has a toString() method, which is called, when you try to concatinate it with a string.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  I really appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return finalList + punctuation + "\n";
```

You are treating the `List` as if it were a string here.. Do you need to do `.toString()` or something similar?

```
asList(T... a)
Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.
```

You are not using the return value either, of `Arrays.asList`